# Distinction betwen system and user python

Tags: 18.04, python, pip

I recently switched to Ubuntu 18.04 after many years of Mac OS. I work a lot in Python and need a simple way of using different versions once in a while. I went with pyenv due to simplicity and that it does what i need and nothing more. I have followed [this guide](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/) and all works fine. I have set it up with Python 3.7.4 in VS code and the blue status bar in VS code says the environment is `~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/bin/python`.

If i open a terminal and run `python --version` it says Python 3.7.4. If i run `which python` it says `/home/name/.pyenv/shims/python` since i currently use `pyenv global 3.7.4`. As i understand, this should not affect system level python, but everything else. Let me just say, that is how i want it to work: When i set a version, then every user-written code should run that python version (without ever touching system python).

Before installing pyenv i thought i could just pip install my packages and be done with it. This means that i think i have installed some packages in python 2.7 and/or 3.6 which came with 18.04. Upon checking, both of these folders are empty:

```
ls -ltd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/*
ls -ltd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/*
```

In fact the site-packages folder is also empty. As far i understand all user installed libraries will go into either of these. So it seems i didn't install any packages, when in fact i know that i did. Were these then saved to the system Python, and is this troublesome?

---

**1.** Where is the system python exactly stored, and where is the user installed python stored? Just like in Mac OS you have system Python in /usr/bin/python while user installed is in usr/local/bin/python.

Is it correct that the python in `usr/local/lib` corresponds to Mac OS's `usr/local/bin`. While `usr/lib` corrsponds to the system python i.e. Mac OS's `usr/bin/python`

I also have some python-related files (not folders) under `usr/bin/` e.g. python 2.7 python3 python3m python3.6 python3.6m etc. What are these files? Under properties it says that it is a "link to executable" so i assume it is simply where the application is stored?

Lastly `usr/lib/` contains 4 python folders: python2.7, python3, python3.6 and python3.7. None of these folders are empty. While `usr/local/lib` have 2 python folders: python2.7 and python3.6 - both of these contain EMPTY site and dist folders.

---

**2.** When i wanted to install some pacakges, I was prompted to upgrade pip. I am afraid i updated the wrong pip. I typed in

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

so without a `3` at the end. Then i kept getting a `"cannot import from main"` error. After some searching on stackexchange i solved this by running

```
hash -d pip
hash -d pip3
```

which ran without any output and everything seemed to go back to normal and works. But the pip of course still got updated from version 9 to 19 if i remember correctly. Now both pip -V and pip3 -V returns 19.2.1. Is there anything wrong with this above. Was there a reason for pip to be so outdated in the first place? Before doing the fix above i got a report crash in Ubuntu saying something was wrong with pip. Never had it occur again since the fix though.

---

**3.** Is there anything else i can do to make sure all python installations are as they should be? Currently i have no problems, but i am simply trying to understand how ubuntu reads the different versions of python, so i don't corrupt the system python.

---

I hope you can help me answer these questions. I've never dealt
too much with it on Mac OS, but know i really want to know how it works. Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you use a virtual env, activate the env and pip install a specific version of python?

Comment: I tried adding version 3.6.5 in a new local environment, and pip did not work. I got the error similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881448/importerror-cannot-import-name-main-after-upgrading-to-pip-10-0-0-for-python). I have not been able to fix it. It still works in my 3.7.4 global environment and in system python.